# Convert File To byte[] in Blazor WA

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I used this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#security-considerations) to download files from Blazor Server and it works fine.

But when I used it with Blazor WA I faced two problems in converting the file into byte[]

first one that when I used the code `string  filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "files\file.rar");` to return the file path it returns "/" instead of the Solution Directory.

So I tried to put a static path into the following Code
`byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\XXX\wwwroot\files\file.rar");

but the File.ReadAllBytes puts "/" before the file path and returns the following error

"Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find file '/D:\XXX\wwwroot\files\file.rar'.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/D:\XXX\wwwroot\files\file.rar'.
File name: '/D:\XXX\wwwroot\files\file.rar"

So the main point that I want to prevent Blazor WA from putting "/" before the file path into the function (File.ReadAllBytes).

And the secondary one is that I want to retrieve the Project folder path using "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" or any other method.